# Кончен и закончен

Tags: грамотная-речь

Когда употреблять слово "кончен", а когда "закончен"?

Answer (score 1):

В современном языке кончен, конченый считаются разговорными вариантами, и употребляются редко, в основном в соченаиях конченый человек, конченое дело и т.д.
В литературной речи следует использовать закончен, окончен.

Answer (score 0):

Мое мнение, кончен - означает что нечто иссякло, убыло окончательно. А закончен - завершен, полностью готов.